# ¿Cómo puedo pintar una lista de puntos en GMaps?

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo un programa en C# con Gmaps, necesito mostrar una lista de latitudes y longitudes que está en un data set, pero necesito que lo haga de forma rapida. Existe algun metodo en gmaps que en vez de pasar punto por punto, le pueda pasar una lista de latitudes y  longitudes para que la muestre?

Comment: de que tipo de proyecto estamos hablando? es winform o web, usas algun componente para generar el mapa

Comment: Es un wondows form, el componente vendria siendo el plugin de gmaps

Comment: cual seria ese plugin? es un componente de terceros

Answer (score 0):

Si usas un componente como ser `GMapControl`

[GMAP.NET TUTORIAL MAPS, MARKERS AND POLYGONS](http://www.independent-software.com/gmap-net-tutorial-maps-markers-and-polygons.html)

puedes crear `markers` pero se crean de a uno porque cada punto requiere una localizacion con las cordenadas

```
GMapOverlay markersOverlay = new GMapOverlay("markers");
GMarkerGoogle marker = new GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(-25.966688, 32.580528), GMarkerGoogleType.green);
markersOverlay.Markers.Add(marker);

gmap.Overlays.Add(markersOverlay);
```

si necesitas agregar varios podrias iterar la lista de marcas he ir creando los `markers` para agregar a la coleccion con el Add()

Salvo que esta lista tenga un `AddRange()` donde puedas asignar directo la lista de markers, pero eso dependera de la implementacion del componente